# Key Error with json file when I try to extract specific values

Tags: python, json, pandas

I want to make a dataframe with all these elements as columns with the following order:

from 'playlists':
'name', 'collaborative', 'pid', 'modified_at', 'num_tracks', 'num_albums', 'num_followers',
'num_edits', 'duration_ms', 'num_artists'

from 'tracks':
'pos',
'artist_name', 'track_uri', 'artist_uri', 'track_name',  'album_uri', 'duration_ms', 'album_name'

from 'info':
'generated_on', 'slice', 'version'

A part of the json file is the following:

```
{
    "info": {
        "generated_on": "2017-12-03 08:41:42.057563", 
        "slice": "0-999", 
        "version": "v1"
    }, 
    "playlists": [
        {
            "name": "Throwbacks", 
            "collaborative": "false", 
            "pid": 0, 
            "modified_at": 1493424000, 
            "num_tracks": 52, 
            "num_albums": 47, 
            "num_followers": 1, 
            "tracks": [
                {
                    "pos": 0, 
                    "artist_name": "Missy Elliott", 
                    "track_uri": "spotify:track:0UaMYEvWZi0ZqiDOoHU3YI", 
                    "artist_uri": "spotify:artist:2wIVse2owClT7go1WT98tk", 
                    "track_name": "Lose Control (feat. Ciara & Fat Man Scoop)", 
                    "album_uri": "spotify:album:6vV5UrXcfyQD1wu4Qo2I9K", 
                    "duration_ms": 226863, 
                    "album_name": "The Cookbook"
                }, 
                {
                    "pos": 1, 
                    "artist_name": "Britney Spears", 
                    "track_uri": "spotify:track:6I9VzXrHxO9rA9A5euc8Ak", 
                    "artist_uri": "spotify:artist:26dSoYclwsYLMAKD3tpOr4", 
                    "track_name": "Toxic", 
                    "album_uri": "spotify:album:0z7pVBGOD7HCIB7S8eLkLI", 
                    "duration_ms": 198800, 
                    "album_name": "In The Zone"
                }, 
 ], 
            "num_edits": 6, 
            "duration_ms": 11532414, 
            "num_artists": 37
        },
```

When I run the program it gives the following error:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_3208/3949258436.py in 
16
17
---> 18 data= pd.json_normalize(js['playlists'],  ['name', 'collaborative', 'pid', 'modified_at', 'num_tracks', 'num_albums',
19                                                     'num_followers', 'tracks', 'num_edits',  'num_artists'], js['info'])
20

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json_normalize.py in _json_normalize(data, record_path, meta, meta_prefix, record_prefix, errors, sep, max_level)
293
294     meta_vals: DefaultDict = defaultdict(list)
--> 295     meta_keys = [sep.join(val) for val in _meta]
296
297     def _recursive_extract(data, path, seen_meta, level=0):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json_normalize.py in (.0)
293
294     meta_vals: DefaultDict = defaultdict(list)
--> 295     meta_keys = [sep.join(val) for val in _meta]
296
297     def _recursive_extract(data, path, seen_meta, level=0):

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, dict found

Here is my code:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import os



path = 'C:\\Users\\sotir\\Desktop\\machinedataset'

filenames = os.listdir(path)
for filename in sorted(filenames):
    if filename.startswith("mpd.slice.") and filename.endswith(".json"):
        fullpath = os.sep.join((path, filename))
        f = open(fullpath)
        js = json.load(f)
        f.close()


data= pd.json_normalize(js['playlists'],  ['name', 'collaborative', 'pid', 'modified_at', 'num_tracks', 'num_albums',
                                                    'num_followers', 'tracks', 'num_edits',  'num_artists'], js['info'])
```

Comment: Can you include a stub data file so we can run the sample code?

Comment: Even better if you can modify your code to include sample data in it which is accessed directly and does not require a separate data file...

Comment: Never mind... Ive stubbed it using the data you provided.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your immediate error, in your `pd.json.normalize()` call, change the last arg from:

```
['info']
```

to:

```
js['info']
```

You'll get further errors, but that is fodder for a new question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, I changed the code to js['info'] but another error appears. I have edited the error and the code.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for Revised Question:

According to https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html, the third arg to `pd.json_normalize()` is `meta=None`

Looking at that doc page (which you definitely need to review), we see:

```
pandas.json_normalize
pandas.json_normalize(data, record_path=None, meta=None, meta_prefix=None, record_prefix=None, errors='raise', sep='.', max_level=None)[source]
Normalize semi-structured JSON data into a flat table.

Parameters:
data: dict or list of dicts
    Unserialized JSON objects.

record_path: str or list of str, default None
    Path in each object to list of records. If not passed, data will be assumed to be an array of records.

meta: list of paths (str or list of str), default None
    Fields to use as metadata for each record in resulting table.
```

According to the docs, `meta` is meant to be a string or list of strings. You're passing in a dict, and that is causing the error.  You need to read the docs to understand how to make the call to `json_normalize()`

Comment: Note: In the future, please do not change a question once it has been answered. If you need further help, please accept the provided answer and ask a new question.